# Python - having to set multiple type handlers when serializing json response

Tags: python, json

I am trying to return a JSON from Django view to client, and have the code below:

```
 ...
 return JsonResponse({'some_qs':json.dumps(list(some_qs), ensure_ascii=False, default=date_default).encode('utf8'),
                         'sum':json.dumps(sum, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')})
```

The problem is that `some_qs` contains dates and decimals. Unless I specify `default` function in `json.dumps`, I will end up with `Decimal('400.0000') is not JSON serializable` or `datetime('....') is not JSON serializable`. I have learnt how to handle the situation when you have ONLY dates or ONLY decimals. In such cases, I use functions like so:

```
def date_default(obj):
    if hasattr(obj, 'isoformat'):
        return obj.isoformat()
    else:
        raise TypeError

def decimal_default(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, decimal.Decimal):
        return float(obj)
    raise TypeError
```

and call set the `default` param of `json.dumps` to `date_default` or `decimal_default` respectively.

**The question**
What syntax for `json.dumps` should be used to pass handlers for BOTH date and decimals ?

Comment: Why can't you combine those functions into one with if/elif?

Comment: Indeed) Stupid me)

Comment: Besides that, there's nothing Django related here.

Comment: Agree. Made respective editions